# Check if vim is compiled with +X11 in .vimrc

Tags: vim, macvim, vimscript

I have two copies of vim installed.

One is installed with macvim and necessarily configured with -X11 (to work with Cocoa), while the other is configured to +X11 (used in terminal, to work with a plugin I use)

I would like all yanks to go to the system clipboard. When +X11 is enabled, I can do this in .vimrc with `set clipboard=unnamedplus`. When -X11, I can do it with `set clipboard=unnamed`.

How can I do this in .vimrc conditionally?

Something like

```
if &x11
 set clipboard=unnamedplus
else
 set clipboard=unnamed
endif
```

Of course this doesn't work because &x11 is not a real variable.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what plugin do you use that requires `+X11`?

Comment: Vim-r-plugin requires it for certain setups

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if has("x11")
   echo "yep"
endif
```